# @Param("myParam") String myParam is Casting to NVARCHAR(4000)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sql-server-2008

I'm writing a simple native query using Hibernate (Spring 2.0.8) but when my param is a String, it is being cast passed as a NVARCHAR(4000), which is leading to performance issues.

Bellow is a sample of my code

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERTO INTO MyTable (a, b, c) SELECT :myParam1, :myParam2, a.xpto FROM myTable a WHERE a.id = :myParam3", nativeQuery = true)
void insertMyTable(@Param("myParam1") String myParam1, @Param("myParam2") String myParam2, @Param("myParam3") int myParam3);
```

The problem is, `myParam1` and `myParam2` are `nvarchar(100)` (example), but when we attach a profiler to SQLServer2008 Instance, we found the execution of the following query

```
@P0 NVARCHAR(4000), @P1 NVARCHAR(4000), @P2 INTEGER

INSERTO INTO MyTable (a, b, c) SELECT @P0, @P1, a.xpto FROM myTable a WHERE a.id = @P2
```

This is leading to a conversion from `NVARCHAR(4000)` to `NVARCHAR(100)` for example and causing performance issues.

Is there anyway to explicity declare @Param with it respective size ? Something like `@Param("myParam1", "nvarchar(100)")`

Comment: actually this is the insert query. Could you have given the wrong column lengths with the create table? Normally it is not recommended to use native Query with Spring jpa. It is designed for HQL. You are using very old version of spring. there is no error in your code

Comment: @ogün This is a simplified version of the current one, we need to use nativeQuery because it have a lot of joins and conversions with other tables for the select statement. The table being used in the insert have the correct column lengths

Answer (score 1):

you can use @Column annotation to specify the data type of column

```
  @Column(columnDefinition="VARCHAR(40)") 
   private String columnName;
```

or

```
  @Column(columnDefinition="text") 
      private String columnName;
```

Comment: In that case we are not using an model, its a native query

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the `columnDefinition` of that variable as text in model class(with this there is no limit to that variable)
like this

```
    @Column(name = "content", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String content;
```

`or` you can directly set the datatype of that variable as text in `database`.

Comment: In that case we are not using an model, its a native query